# use jQuery serializeArray on only one form input

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have a form that is pretty standard, except for one set of inputs that can be cloned. The form can be [viewed here](https://jsfiddle.net/c8zvqtct/2/).

The form data needs to be submitted as such:

- q2_fullName[first]:first (standard form field)
- q1_currentCommission1:[{"Instruments":"ins1","Commissions":"4","Margins":"ins1marg"},{"Instruments":"ins2","Commissions":"5","Margins":"ins2marg"}] (cloned form fields as object)

here is the submit handler I'm trying to use:

```
$.ajax({
                type:$('form[name="form_60065580423955"]').attr('method'),
                url: form.action,
                data: ???,
                // this is where I need to serialize all the normal form fields and serializArray the cloned form fields
                beforeSend: function(data){
                  console.log('before send');
                },
                success: function(data){
                  console.log('success');
                }
              });
```

I am not sure how to submit the form so that only one input, the cloned ones are submitted as a json object.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of jQuery.serializeArray, I think that in your case [form2js](https://github.com/maxatwork/form2js) is best suited: this library can output a json object from your form inputs, provided that you name your inputs accordingly.

For example, you should use as `name`attribute for your input fields:

- `q1_currentCommission1[x].Instruments` for Instruments input fields
- `q1_currentCommission1[x].Commissions` for Commissions input fields
- `q1_currentCommission1[x].Margins` for Margin input fields

Instead of [x] use [0], 1, 2 and so on. Applying form2js to this form will result in the JSON structure you described.